# Распознание звуков в Android

Tags: android, аудио

Как сделать распознание звуков в Android? То есть если открыто мое приложение, звучит данный звук и приложение должно среагировать на него. Что-то типа Шазама.

Comment: В Android места не хватит на это, Шазам распознает у себя на серваке https://laplacian.wordpress.com/2009/01/10/how-shazam-works/

Answer (score 1):

Здравствуйте.Сравниваете спектр звучания со спектром звука который надо найти при помощи функции кореляции или автокореляции,уже точно не помню как называется,смысл в том что оба звука представляются как единичные вектора в многомерном(......) пространстве и находится наибольшая их похожесть))))
В общем начните вникать с разложения спектра с помощью теоремы Фурье.)))